# C pthread join an ended thread

Tags: c, join, pthreads, pthread-join

I'm building 2 programs (client/server) that communicate through FIFOs. Both programs have threads. When the Client's thread ends it doesn't get joined, and main hangs.

The programs do the following:

Server:

1. main: reads from FIFO1
2. main: create thread to process request.
3. main: goto 1
4. thread: processes request
5. thread: sends response to FIFO2
6. thread: exit

Client:

1. main: spawn thread
2. thread: reads X responses to client from FIFO2
3. thread: exit
4. main: sends X requests to FIFO1
5. main: wait thread to exit
6. main: check responses

The server works well and all threads are joined accordingly.

The client fails in step 5. Using

```
pthread_join(&reader,NULL);
```

hangs main forever. I've checked, and the thread already ended.

Using

```
pthread_tryjoin_np(&reader,NULL);
```

I get

> errorcode=16

strerror gives

> Device or resource busy

Creating the thread with:

```
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
pthread_create(&reader,&attr,trataResp,NULL);
```

Or with:
    pthread_create(&reader,NULL,trataResp,NULL);

doesn't produce any change.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please post your client thread's code

Comment: How did you check that the thread already ended?

Comment: Nighthawk I just printed something right before returning.

@Jay, the bug was corrected by Fred, but if you still wish I can post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well pthread_join receives the thread id, not the address for it. This line:

```
pthread_join(&reader,NULL);
```

Should be:

```
pthread_join(reader,NULL);
```

If `reader` was declared as `pthread_t`.

Hope it's not just a typo in your question and that this actually helps.